# Can the results of dbt test be converted to report

Tags: python, json, reporting, dbt

I am using DBT (data build tool) as an ETL tool for data analytics . 
The command 
`dbt test`
Resuts in the test cases being pass/fail on the output terminal but need to export this result into JSON/HTML/XML format for reporting.

Any help in this regard ?

Comment: Can I ask, where are you running dbt form?

Comment: @FrancescoPaoloGalletta, Currently I am running dbt on my local but plan to integrate this to my CI/CD solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are executing this on an UNIX shell like Mac or Linux, you can try with `tee` like this.

`dbt run | tee -a your_log_file.txt`

This will create and append there on the a log file of your choosing for whatever results of the `dbt run` command.

Comment: Thanks @FrancescoPaoloGalletta , that would create another file with dbt run results but  I would want in to be in a more presentable format for reporting lke HTML/XML/JSON... I was looking to export this result into a report and I could not find a tool to do so

Comment: I see, so basically a out-of-the-box report dbt runs. 
I think using this to collect the logs and then you can parse them easily as a report using REGEXs, or using dbt's API are your only options. Hope someone has a more creative idea though.

Comment: Yes you are right and I am also trying the parsing solution but don't know about dbt apis . If there is some other easier approach then that would be welcome

Answer (score 4):

We export this into our logs as json using the `—log-format` flag. This is a global flag so can be used with `dbt test` as well as `dbt run`.

Details here:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/running-a-dbt-project/command-line-interface/global-cli-flags/#log-formatting

Also there are useful json artefacts created in the target directory e.g. `manifest.json`, `run_results.json` that can be parsed to find additional metadata you’ve added.

Unfortunately, I don’t know any out-of-the-box solutions to turn all this into a report. However, parsing the JSON of these items gets some good stuff. This can be done using logging tools like [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/) or by hand using Python libraries/dicts.

Furthermore, if you name your tests in a defined way, you can then do some regex on the names to get some details that way too.